# How change the control language?

Tags: wpf-extended-toolkit

I'm using `wpf-extended-toolkit` 'cause wpf doesn't have any `ColorPicker`. But I noticed that there is no support for the multilanguage, in particular the control is in english, I want change the label "Available Colors",  "Standards Colors" and "Advanced" in italian language..

[image]

Someone know how do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Available Colors" and Standard Colors" labels, as well as the "Advanced" and "Standard" button labels, can all be modified using the following properties on the ColorPicker: AvailableColorsHeader, StandardColorsHeader, StandardButtonHeader and AdvancedButtonHeader.

I used Google Translate, so my apologies if any of the translations are off.

```
<xctk:ColorPicker x:Name="italianColorPicker"
                  Margin="20" Width="100" Height="25"
                  AvailableColorsHeader="Colori disponibili"
                  StandardColorsHeader="Colori standard"
                  StandardButtonHeader="Standard"
                  AdvancedButtonHeader="Avanzate" />
```

Comment: How to change the language of colors?

Comment: Please check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48038798/how-to-change-language-of-colors